# Open problems in quantum algorithms

Tags: quantum-algorithms, resource-request

I am new to the field of quantum algorithms. It is well known that quantum algorithms offer a speedup over classical algorithms in some problems. Regarding the problems in which quantum algorithms offer a speed up, I need to know the problems that don't yet have a quantum algorithm for them. Is there any kind of website that offers such problems that need quantum algorithms?

Comment: I think there isn't a lot quantum algorithms that offer a speed up over classical algorithms in some problems, here is a list https://quantumalgorithmzoo.org/. Therefore you just have to find a problem (And there are many) who does not belong to this list.

Comment: @lufydad i am not an expert to know what kind of problems that need algorithms, so i am asking for suggestions.

Comment: @OmarAli I see what you mean, but "problems that need quantum algorithms" it's a little bit vague. Could you be more precise ? Like problem in quantum chemestry ? in algebra ?

Comment: @lufydad ya in algebra will be nice, or any sort of thing like the problem solved by Shor's algorithm.

Comment: @OmarAli sorry for responding so late. I think you can look for Gram-Schmidt algorithm (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gram%E2%80%93Schmidt_process), Triangularisability (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_matrix#Triangularisability). And I think there is a lot of work to do on solving a system of linear equations (ie. https://scottaaronson.com/papers/qml.pdf).